# how to setup a alert on machine learning toolkit for historical data

Tags: machine-learning, splunk

I am working on a splunk  time series forcasting poc and needed to show how splunk send alert when the prediction returns a result above threshold.
the search | inputlookup internet_traffic.csv | timechart span=120min avg("bits_transferred") as bits_transferred | eval bits_transferred=round(bits_transferred) , if predicts bits_trasferred above the condition given in alert should send email to mentioned id.
Currently the condition give is per result of the search. 
Kindly let me know how to set up the alert or which condition to setup.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example using the Splunk core function, `predict`, but you should be able to also apply it to the Machine Learning Toolkit

```
| inputlookup internet_traffic.csv | timechart span=120min avg("bits_transferred") as bits_transferred | eval bits_transferred=round(bits_transferred) | predict bits_transferred | where bits_transferred > 'upper95(prediction(bits_transferred))'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Machine Learning Toolkit actually has a showcase example that you can tweak that illustrates detecting anomalies with MLTJ=K

```
/en-US/app/Splunk_ML_Toolkit/detect_numeric_outliers?ml_toolkit.dataset=Employee%20Logins%20(prediction%20errors)
```